# Redirecting */test/* in httpd.conf to */* [Removing /test/ in path]

Tags: url-rewriting, apache

we've been running a test verions of our site at www.mystie.com/test/ and these urls are being used by everyday people... how can i configure httpd.conf to now redirect all these old urls to the / location?

ie,

```
www.mysite.com/test/image1.jpg
```

should be:

```
www.mysite.com/image1.jpg
```

There are other httpd conf rules in there, so i assume i 'll have to place this up front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add these lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

If lines 1 and 2 have already been set, then you can omit those.

If you prefer, you can add this into your `.htaccess` file in the root web directory instead. Slightly slower, but saves restarting httpd.

Comment: it actually worked with RewriteRule ^/test/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would need a 301 redirect (which should help in SEO as well)

Redirect 301 /test/ /

Answer (score 0):

Looks like @melkamo has the .htaccess covered.

The `alias_module` will allow you to do it in httpd.conf

```
`Redirect permanent /test http://localhost`
```

It will erase `test` from the URL if it is the first subdirectory